# acquiring float properties from supclass to super

Tags: java, casting, awt, multiple-inheritance, superclass

im creating a paint project like app for school and in my current code i have a several subclasses and a super. The super should hold the an array of the shapes to draw and every shape object should be its own subclass that i later have to put into a Array and call from the app. I have to use JDesktopPane and JInternalFrame, I cant use Arraylists and Im currently stuck on trying to cast the Float of my RectDraw subclass to my super. All this before finally nesting the tools in a super named MyShapes. any help is welcomed. I dont used jdesktopPane much and im bad at casting.

```
        public class myShapes {

            public void paint(Graphics g) {

                graphSettings = (Graphics2D)g;
                graphSettings.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                graphSettings.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4));

                Iterator<Color> strokeCounter = shapeStroke.iterator();
                Iterator<Color> fillCounter = shapeFill.iterator();
                Iterator<Float> transCounter = transPercent.iterator();

                for (Shape s : shapes){
                    graphSettings.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, transCounter.next()));
                    graphSettings.setPaint(strokeCounter.next());
                    graphSettings.draw(s);
                    graphSettings.setPaint(fillCounter.next());
                    graphSettings.fill(s);
                    }


                if (drawStart != null && drawEnd != null){

                    graphSettings.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.40f));
                    graphSettings.setPaint(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

                    Shape aShape = null;                            

                    if (currentAction == 2){                            
                        RectDraw drawRectangle = new RectDraw();
                        aShape = drawRectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2);                     
                    } 
                    else if (currentAction == 3){                           
                        CircleDraw drawEllipse = new CircleDraw();
                        aShape = drawEllipse(x1, y1, x2, y2);
                    } 
                    else if (currentAction == 4) {
                        LineDraw drawLine = new LineDraw();
                        aShape = drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
                    }

                    graphSettings.draw(aShape);
                    }
                }
            }
```

These are my Sub Classes

```
package mainPackage;

import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

public class RectDraw extends myShapes {

public Rectangle2D.Float drawRectangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {

    int RDx, RDy, RDwidth, RDheight;

    RDx = Math.min(x1, x2);
    RDy = Math.min(y1, y2);
    RDwidth = Math.abs(x1 - x2);
    RDheight = Math.abs(y1 - y2);

    return new Rectangle2D.Float(RDx, RDy, RDwidth, RDheight);
}
}
```

the others are completely the same save for the names

```
public class CircleDraw extends myShapes {

public Ellipse2D.Float drawEllipse(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){

     int x = Math.min(x1, x2);
     int y = Math.min(y1, y2);
     int width = Math.abs(x1 - x2);
     int height = Math.abs(y1 - y2);

     return new Ellipse2D.Float(x, y, width, height);
 }
}


public class LineDraw extends myShapes {

    public Line2D.Float drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {

        return new Line2D.Float(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
}
```

I keep getting cannot be resolved to a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  RectDraw drawRectangle = new RectDraw();
  aShape = drawRectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2);
```

Based on the 1st line drawRectangle is a instance of RectDraw;

In the second line you're confusing your reference name "drawRectangle" with the method of same name in RectDraw class

You have to call the method using the instance of your RectDraw class like below..changing the instance name for clarity

```
  RectDraw rectDraw = new RectDraw();
  aShape = rectDraw.drawRectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2);
```

Same issue for all shapes..

Also you're creating a lot of instances in a loop which is not a good practice.

Comment: i see. i apologize. its so much u have to do and I still am not acustomed to using super classes and or the inheritance structure in java. c++ and c# are just easier for me

Comment: no need to apologize.. Just make sure you stick with documentation when coding with language of your choice. And using an IDE never hurts, it will show you a lot of compile time errors while you're coding and please select answer if any of it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add that this is not a good class hierarchy. Your shapes should extend from a base Shape Abstract Class, then on your main method you can create a list of shapes.

You can't access the "super class" objects because the shapes are not instance variables. I wouldn't use a myShapes class but if you must you should probably separate Shape methods to  Shape.java class and let myShapes.java class take care of shape list creations.

```java
abstract class Shape(){
    abstract void draw();
}
```

Then your other subclass shapes should extend and implement paint method:

```java
public class Rectangle extends Shape(){
    //instance variables
    public void draw();
}
```

On a main method:

```java
Shape[] myShapesArray = new Shape()[10];
```

I would suggest looking up factory pattern. [Factory](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm) It will make much sense to use it, and clean up your code. Also limiting to Array and not using Lists make things a bit harder to manage for a drawing application. Since you'll always need to know how many items you need at array initialization.